# docker-compose mounted directory does not rename folders

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

So I have gotten a folder to rename in a directory. Every other folder I put in that mounted directory says:

> Warning:
>   rename(/app/public/CoverImages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth/2019-01-15-Uploaded,/app/public/CoverImages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth/2019-01-15-Uploaded-AWS):
>   Permission denied in /app/src/S3CoverImages.php on line 260

My php code is the following:

```
if(is_dir($dirPath)) {
            $success = rename(rtrim($dirPath, " -/"), rtrim($dirPath, " -/") . "-AWS");
```

My dockerfile code for permissions is as follows:

```
RUN chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /app && \
  chmod -R 755 /app && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www && \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start.sh; sync
```

In docker-compose.yml we have it mounting the directory we need:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    nginx:
        image: americanreading/someproject:dev
        restart: on-failure:3
        ports:
          - 8001:8080
    php:
        image: americanreading/bisapi-php:dev
        environment:
            #lots of server details here. 
        volumes:
            - /mnt/coverimages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth:/app/public/CoverImages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth/
```

Is there something else I need to make sure any folder put into this mounted directory will have php permission to rename the folder? Is there anything evident that I am not doing at the moment?

Almost forgot, here are the current permissions we looked up in bash:

```
arcit@arcvm13:~/arcbis-dev$ docker-compose run --rm php bash
www-data@9a78e9799427:/app$ ls -la /app/public/CoverImages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth/
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb 25 14:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 25 14:38 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6148 Feb 25 14:32 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 Oct 20  2015 2010-02-15
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 Feb 25 14:30 2019-01-15-Uploaded
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 Feb 25 14:31 2019-02-07-Uploaded-AWS
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 Feb 22 16:24 2019-02-18
```

Here is the ls -la on the subfolder-for-depth itself:

```
drwx------@ 1 toddcoulson  staff  16384 Oct 20  2015 2010-02-15
drwx------@ 1 toddcoulson  staff  16384 Feb 25 09:30 2019-01-15-Uploaded
drwx------  1 toddcoulson  staff  16384 Feb 25 09:31 2019-02-07-Uploaded-AWS
drwx------@ 1 toddcoulson  staff  16384 Feb 22 11:24 2019-02-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is created when you run the container, not when you build it. By default the permissions on that directory will be `root`.

An other issue here is that you are binding your volume to a host path *"/mnt/coverimages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth"*.
So that directory is going to have the permissions of your host (for example user `1000`).
A solution is to add that user the the `www-data` group, in your Dockerfile.

Comment: all the permissions are the same for 4 folders, one of them has permissions, and the others do not let me rename the folder. So I don't think it is an owner issue. I tried to add permissions to www-data already for my app folder. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: The issue is not the `app/` folder but the volume you are binding in that folder. Why folders in `subfolder-for-depth/` are owned by **root**? Aren't those generated by your script run by www-data?

Comment: I am not generating any folders, I just want to take a folder on my machine and mount it for a script to automatically put files up on aws. I have the code working, but not all of the folders in the subfolder-for-depth folder are allowing permission. I am not generating any folders in code though.

Comment: I added file_put_contents($dirPath.'/newfile.txt', 'Making sure the file writes') and the folder allows the file to be created, but does not let me rename the folder.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `ls -la /app/public/CoverImages/S3-Uploaded/subfolder-for-depth/`?

Comment: updated the post, you are right, it is on the actual folder not in the permissions once in docker. What is the @ sign permission? And how can I change this?

Comment: Ok, and do you have the same permissions issue when you rename the folder manually with **mv**, in the container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189006/discussion-between-zak-and-tcoulson).